# Смоделировать консольный ввод Enter

Tags: java, многопоточность

Есть класс `TestThread` который запускает класс `Writer` который печатает сообщения и останавливается по нажатию клавиши Enter в консоли. В классе `TestMain` вызывается метод `main()` класса `TestThread`, в нем же нужно смоделировать консольный ввод Enter (пустая строка или `lineSeparator()`) через 2 секунды после запуска, чтобы остановить поток. Как мне заменить стандартный поток ввода, так чтобы можно было смоделировать это? Обязательно с помощью потоков.

```
public class TestThread {

    Thread thread = new Writer();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        TestThread testThread = new TestThread();

        testThread.start();

        while (true) {
            if (in.nextLine().equals("")) {
                testThread.end();
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    public void start(){
        thread.start();
    }
    public void end(){
        thread.interrupt();
    }

    private class Writer extends Thread{

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                while (!isInterrupted()) {
                    sleep(1000);
                    System.out.println("Something");
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }
        }
    }

}
```

```
public class TestMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //вот тут нужно заменить поток ввода на наш, как я понимаю
        //System.setIn(OUR_INPUT_STREAM);
        Thread thread = new Thread(()->{TestThread.main(null); });
        thread.start();
        //а тут смоделировать нажатие Enter с задержкой 




    }
}
```

Comment: Может `sendKeys(Keys.ENTER)`?

Comment: Еще есть `keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);`  или `keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);`